# Order by clause not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

LINQ- I have used order by clause to order in ascending to get all states available in database but it is not working.
This is the code:

```
 public List<State> GetAllStates()
    {
        List<State> p;
        p = (from a in _db.ProductImageMaps
             where a.State != "" && a.State != null
             select new State
             {
                 Name = a.State
             }).OrderBy(a=>a.Name).Distinct().ToList();
        return p;

    }
```

Comment: please define "not working"; what are you expecting, and what are you getting?

Comment: there is not a linq problem here, you may have an issue about accessing data

Comment: See. I am getting different names of states but not alphabetically. When i try to use order by clause, it doesn't make any difference to the output. This is what i was asking.

Answer (score 2):

By Design [Disitnct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348456) returns an unordered sequence of the unique items in source.

And as you are calling Distinct after your order by clause therefore, you are loosing the sequence you are after. Secondly, calling OrderBy after Distinct makes more sense to me as it would be more efficient to Order only Distinct Records.

do it like this

```
public List<State> GetAllStates()
    {
        List<State> p;
        p = (from a in _db.ProductImageMaps
             where a.State != "" && a.State != null
             select new State
             {
                 Name = a.State
             }).Distinct().OrderBy(a=>a.Name).ToList();
        return p;

    }
```